# How to recover deleted words in samsung mobile

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I am using Samsung s duos 2 7582 mobile. Accidentally I deleted few words like 
***to***, ***this*** etc. I want to recover those words. Kindly help how to recover these words.

Comment: You mean you deleted these from the suggestions dictionary? Doesn't it have a personal dictionary to add them to?

Comment: yeah deleted them from suggestion dictionary.... i usually type with dictionary ON mode

Comment: No way. You cannot *recover* them. Just add them into dictionary again and that's it.

Comment: @Suncatcher how to do that? can you help please.

Comment: see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please go the following way to add a new word:

- Settings
- Language and keyboard
- User dictionary
- Press the menu button
  Select *Add*
- Type in the new word
  Select *OK.*

These steps are intended for the stock JellyBean ROM which Galaxy S7582 should have been equipped with, for other ROMs steps may be different.
If User Dictionary applet is not available in Settings, you can try to use QuickShortcutMaker app to access it ([manual here](http://www.martinkem.com/2013/05/how-to-add-edit-words-in-user.html))

Comment: there is no user dictionary in Samsung s duos 2 7582 :(

Comment: It seems you're running not a factory stock, but some other ROM. Check your [ROM version/type](http://www.wikihow.com/Check-What-Android-Version-You-Have). And have you tried QuickShortcutMaker way?